# What is proper way to forward declare NS_OPTIONS in Objective-C\C++

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm generating bridges from cpp to swift using cpp-objcpp-objc chain and I need to generate NS_OPTIONS.
In ObjC I have it as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, PhonebookPhoneOptions)
{
    PhonebookPhoneOptionsOpt1 = 1 << 0,
    PhonebookPhoneOptionsOpt2 = 1 << 1,
    PhonebookPhoneOptionsOpt3 = 1 << 2,
    PhonebookPhoneOptionsOpt4 = 1 << 3,
};
```

It is forward-declared in my another header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, PhonebookPhoneOptions);
//typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PhonebookPhoneOptions);

@protocol PhonebookDataRefreshedCallback

- (void)onEvent:(PhonebookPhoneOptions)param;
```

When I use NS_OPTIONS forward declaration I'm getting following error:
With NS_ENUM forward it is as folows:

> subprojects/controller/service-sbis-phonebook/phonebook/djinni/objc/phonebook/PhonebookDataRefreshedCallback.h:5:53:
> error: unnamed enumeration must be a definition typedef
> NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, PhonebookPhoneOptions);
>
> subprojects/controller/service-sbis-phonebook/phonebook/djinni/objc/phonebook/PhonebookDataRefreshedCallback.h:5:9:
> error: declaration does not declare anything
> [-Werror,-Wmissing-declarations] typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger,
> PhonebookPhoneOptions);

With NS_ENUM it is as follows:

> subprojects/controller/service-sbis-phonebook/phonebook/djinni/objc/phonebook/PhonebookPhoneOptions.h:6:31:
> error: typedef redefinition with different types ('NSInteger' (aka
> 'long') vs 'enum PhonebookPhoneOptions') typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger,
> PhonebookPhoneOptions)
>
> subprojects/controller/service-sbis-phonebook/phonebook/djinni/objc/phonebook/PhonebookDataRefreshedCallback.h:5:28:
> note: previous definition is here typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,
> PhonebookPhoneOptions);

When it was used solely as structure field I got some combination of NS_ENUM\NS_OPTIONS in ObjC\ObjC++ that was working, but when I try to use it as a function argument - it doesn't compile in any of the variants. What is the correct way to do such forward declaration?

Comment: Enums isn't forward declarable, is it? But pointers are always forward declarable. You can use pointer at enum or can use `NSValue`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to *forward* declare these sensibly. Can't you simply pack the *definition* into a header file with no other content so it can be `#include`d from just about anywhere? So, have a header file that contains nothing other than your enum, then include/import that from anything that needs it without pulling in any transitive dependencies.

If your problem is that `NS_ENUM`/`NS_OPTIONS` isn't available in pure C++, or rather, that `#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>` does not work there, try `CF_ENUM`/`CF_OPTIONS` instead, which are equivalent and defined in `<CoreFoundation/CFAvailability.h>`, which can be used from any of the C/C++/ObjC/ObjC++.

If that doesn't help you, please update your question to explain in more detail why you are trying to *forward* declare your enum type. As in, what specific problem arises as a result of not forward declaring the type? (provide minimal repro code)

Comment: `#define NS_OPTIONS(_type, _name) CF_OPTIONS(_type, _name)` already in `Foundation` so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Adding the line `#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>` produces errors in a pure C++ (rather than Objective-C++) compilation unit, as it assumes an Objective-C capable compiler. (source.cpp, not source.mm) So yes, they are equivalent because one's just a macro wrapper around the other, but it's defined in a header you can't include everywhere. Granted, it's not clear from the question whether it needs to be used in pure C++, but it's also not clear from the question *why* @CrazySage wants to forward-declare, so I'm trying to anticipate possible reasons.

Comment: Forward-declare of NS_CLOSED_ENUM works ok in our project.

Comment: It seems that it'd be much easier to import instead of forward declare, yes. I tried it first time, but got lot of errors. Seems that I just imported it wrong that time.